# How do I get the base path?

Tags: theming

I want to use the base path in a Drupal 8 template file. I tried the following, but I don't get the correct result.

```
{{ app.request.baseUrl  }}

{{base_path}}
```

What I need is the absolute path to the node `{{ app.request.baseUrl  }}/{{ url }}`.

One solution I found is putting  this code in a preprocess hook, and pass it to the theme.

```
 $host = \Drupal::request()->getHost(); 
$response = \Drupal::httpClient()
```

I am looking for a better solution. What could should I use instead of the one I am using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And According to [Page Documentation on 8.2.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21seven%21templates%21page.html.twig/8.2.x) , two global variables added to return front page  and Base Path Urls :

> front_page: The URL of the front page. Use this instead of base_path
>   when linking to the front page. This includes the language domain or
>   prefix.
>
> base_path: The base URL path of the Drupal installation. Will usually
>   be "/" unless you have installed Drupal in a sub-directory.

**So** you can get font page Url with `front_page` and base Url with `base_url`

**Note**

getting front page url with  `{{ url('<front>') }}` has a issue when you want concat it with other path, as example

```
{%  set base_url = url('<front>')  %}
{% set url = [ base_url,'/landing-page?invitecode=' ,invite_code] | join  %}
{{ url }}
```

return

```
Array/landing-page?invitecode=
```

this mean by default is not text and return a render able array to twig

Answer (score 48):

You can use `url()` to generate a base url to any route in Drupal. You can supply the `<front>` route which, in effect, will be your base URL.

```
{{ url('<front>') }}
```

But, **render** it first if you're concatenating it:

```
{{ url('<front>')|render ~ file_url('public://image.jpg') }}
```

For example:

```
{{ url('<front>') ~ file_url('public://image.jpg') }}
# Outputs: "Array/sites/all/default/files/image.jpg"

{{ url('<front>')|render ~ file_url('public://image.jpg') }}
# Outputs: "http://example.com/sites/all/default/files/image.jpg"
```

Comment: and if I want get node absolute path?

Comment: In a node context, the `path()` function can be applied to retrieve node route: `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}`

Comment: when i try {{ url('<front>')|render ~ file_url('public://image.jpg') }} i get http://example.com//sites/mysite/files/image.jpg - NOTE, the double // between front and public file path.

Answer (score 17):

In `page.html.twig` you *will* have a working `{{ base_path }}` variable.  Why it isn't available in every template, i have no idea.  As i think it should be and everything else looks messy, my preferred solution is to do exactly as Drupal does in the preprocess page function for any place i need it.

To make `{{ base_path }}` available to block templates in a theme named example, add this code to the `example.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
 */
function example_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

  $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
}
```

As noted in the accepted answer provided by MPD, if getting a node's or other entity's URL there are methods to do it all for you.

However, there are reasons for getting the base_path, such as when displaying images that live in your theme folder.  `{{ directory }}` provides the path to the theme folder, but it leaves off the base path (usually just a / but in order to preserve Drupal's proper functioning from a subdirectory of a domain that shouldn't be hardcoded).  On `page.html.twig` or in any template which has the above preprocesser, this will work for that purpose:

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/images/nsf1.svg"
     alt="National Science Foundation logo" height="80" width="80" />
```

And of course Shawn Conn's answer works fine if you can suppress your desire for pretty templates, but i couldn't.

Comment: base_path() is returning "/" in the "hook_preprocess_block" but if I use it in "hook_preprocess" I get the absolute url of my domain, why is this?

Answer (score 13):

You almost never need to explicitly build up paths from parts in Drupal 8.  I would go with something like this:

```
function FOO_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['url'] = $node->toUrl('canonical', [
    'absolute' => TRUE,
    'language' => $node->language(),
  ])->toString();
}
```

Comment: pologize me to edit your answer, but url now is a object, we should convert it to string.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that, the template can handle the url object.It is nice to other modules to keep the object, so that anyone can change it it at any stage, before it gets rendered finally in twig.

Comment: @4k4 but I tried without `toString` but noting show, then I tried kint(url) and saw it is object.

Comment: I agree with @4k4 that it should not be converted into string and left as object so that other methods/functions consuming it are not affected.

Answer (score 12):

All of the above failed for me, because I have language paths setup, so my front page URL looks like `https://example.com/en`.

I ended up using this code to get the actual base URL for my site:

```
{% set base_url = url('<front>')|render|split('/', -1)|join('/') %}
```

Answer (score 4):

So far this thread doesn't bring any proper solution. We can concatenate it by using render_val()

Here is the way I used it, to get the absolute path of an entity image:

```
{% set base_url = render_var(url('<front>'))  %}
{% set url = base_url|trim('/', 'right')~file_url(content.field_media[0]['#media'].get('field_image').entity.uri.value)  %}
```

1st we get the base URL of the site.
Then we need to remove an extra /. Then we concatenate our base path with our image relative path.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
function hook_preprocess(&$variables) {
  $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
}
```

& in template file u can call via

```
{{ base_path ~ directory }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ path('<front>') }}
```

I know you've already marked this as correct, but this can be used as a twig element in a template file without any extra work. I found this in the block--system-branding-block.html.twig from the Classy theme. So you can use it like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
```